# Getting the bonus on the tiller side-quest

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

So I just completed the tiller side quest on H-047c but there is one last console I can't get an observer to.

I've tried to spawn several but none of them follow to that particular one.

On the screenshot below, Ryder is standing right next to that console and says that we need an observer for this. Where do you summon that observer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On that side, you can spawn a Observer at the very bottom of the area, towards the end.

When you move into one of the door ways that close one door and open another, your observer will follow you into it. Simply spawn the observer at the bottom, then enter the doorway, wait till it goes in, open the other door, repeat for the next door, then scan the terminal.